# How to store Data Using Shared Preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i am making a simple application in which user enter the input in edit text widget .I want to store the String using Shared preference .

Comment: Have your tried (re)searching?

Comment: Could you show us effort, which you put to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to search in google before asking the question, For Shared Preference check this [**Saving key-value sets**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here's your research.
There are enough examples and information for your question here.

[Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: Should've linked a lmgtfy query, lol